# table view section background color xamarin android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, tableview

i'm developing a new app in xamarin forms (xaml/c#). I have in a xaml page a tableview with a tableview section with the title. How i can change the background color of only table section? I can change it in all table view, but I want to change color only for table section. I'm new in developing, Is there a simple solution? Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Here is XAML solution (Background part):

```
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Silver">
                        <Grid Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" 
                            FontSize="Medium" 
                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                            TextColor="Black" 
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                            BackgroundColor="Red"
                        />
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```